Question regarding the nature of derivative of a function.
This question is in regard to the following problem
The complete range of values of $a$ such that $(\frac{1}{2})^{|x|} = x^2 - a$ is satisfied for maximum of values $x$ is:
How i approached this problem is as follows, plugging in 0 in the place of $x$ gives the value of $a = -1$ rearranging the equation.
$$a = x^2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{|x|}$$
If we can prove that this function is strictly increasing after $x = 0$
then we can prove that the answer to this question is one of the options.
The derivative of the above function is,
$$2x - \frac{ln(2)\cdot x}{2^{|x|}\cdot |x|}$$
By plugging in some arbitrary values and some observation it is quite intuitive that this derivative will always be positive from $x = 0$ to $x = \infty$.
However i wanted a concrete proof for this, could someone point me in the right direction, any help would be appreciated.

See my new answer ;)

If I understand your problem correctly, you are asked to find the values of the parameter $a$ for which the equation $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|x|} = x^2 - a$ admits the maximum number of solutions. This problem is actually equivalent (assuming that you want to work on the reals, so that $|x| = x^2$) to studying the zeros of the function $f(x) = x^2 - a - 2^{-|x|}$, which is a kind of pointed parabola when plotted, hence two zeros at most.
Let's study the said function and more particularly find its global minimum. Let's consider the restriction to the domain $x \ge 0$ for the moment, where $f_+(x) = x^2 - a - 2^{-x}$ hence $f_+'(x) = 2x + 2^{-x}\ln2 > 0 \;\forall x \ge 0$, meaning that it is a strictly increasing function. Due to the even parity of $f$ (or, equivalently, invoking the same kind of arguments for $f_-(x) = x^2 - 2^x$ on $x \le 0$), we can deduce that its minimum lies at $x = 0$.
Now, given that $f$ is continuous and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = +\infty$, we conclude that it will intercept the axis of abscissa twice if $f(0) < 0$, once if $f(0) = 0$ and finally never in the case where $f(0) > 0$. Since $f(0) = 1 - a$, these three cases correspond to $a \gtreqqless 1$ respectively.

Side note.
If you admit the relation $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x| = \mathrm{sgn}(x)$, where $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ denotes the signum function, then you can study the first derivative of $f$ straighforwardly, because $f'(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x)(2|x| - 2^{-|x|}\ln2)$.
